# How to Reduce my Stomach?

Tags: stomach

I'm 5.6FT tall & my weight is 115 KG. i'm sitting all the day in the office & because of that i have a Big Stomach. i want to reduced it.. can any one advice me is their any medicine to do this

Comment: 5 sets of 5 fork put-downs and plate push-aways. Eat less to lose weight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most important is what you eat. Search information of a what to eat, basically is avoid sugar, eating a lot of vegetables and having a low-calorie diet.

The second step is burn calories, to do that you can run or swim. It's necessary to do cardiovascular activity.

Rely on frequency of your cardiovascular activity on week, you will see the results at same frequency.

Comment: Not necessary to do cardio to lose weight. Definitely helpful, but not essential to the process. Losing weight is all about Calories In vs Calories Out

Comment: In this case it is not directly about lose weight but lose belly fat, and to burn this fat it's essential do cardiovascular sport.

Comment: You cannot spot-reduce fat anywhere on your body. You can lose weight but you cannot choose where you lose it from and in what order

Comment: Yes that right! I'm talking to fat in general, even if the question was belly fat.

Comment: Ok, but if you eat less calories than you need then your body will use mostly your fat stores for energy, making you lose weight. Cardio helps and is great, but is not essential.